# How can I connect to AirPort Extreme Shared Drive upon login?

Tags: networking, mount, disk, shared-folders

I'm new to Ubuntu but I have successfully used the "Connect to Server" menu option in the Places window to connect to my external USB drive, which is shared on my Airport Extreme. I use the IP address and it lets me right in, no problem.

I would like to be able to have this drive always available to me rather than having to run the "connect to server" option all the time. I have been unable to get it working. I have seen a few tutorials but none seem to work in 14.04.

Comment: Adding the steps that you already tried, will improve your question and encourages users to help you.